# Facebook share extension, sharing image and link

Tags: ios, facebook

It seems Facebook has recently broken (or intentionally removed?) the ability to share images and links in one post via their share extension, trying to share an image with a link now results in only the image posting.  Sharing only the link works and generates a post with an image preview of the linked page.

Previously you could share images and links in one post, is there a way to restore this functionality with the after Facebook app v29?

Here's a brief sample that illustrates what previously worked, but now only shares the image.

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[
                           [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"], 
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareImage"]
                          ];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

*Update*
 - Facebook has acknowledged this as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949486035103197/)

Answer (score 4):

*As per Facebook latest SDK v4.0.1. we can surely share image and link but not both at same time.*

---

**Sharing URL Link and image URL (not Image):-**

***FBSDKShareLinkContent*** model includes attributes that show up in the post:

**contentURL** - the link to be shared

**contentTitle** - represents the title of the content in the link

**imageURL** - the URL of thumbnail image that appears on the post

**contentDescription** - of the content, usually 2-4 sentences

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
content.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nasa.org/a.jpg"];
content.contentTitle=@"Facebook Share";
content.contentDescription=@"Lets see, How my share works guyz..";
[FBSDKShareDialog shareFromViewController:self
                              withContent:content
                                 delegate:nil];
```

---

**Sharing Only Image:-**

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = self.imgView.image;// you can edit it by your choice
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
```

Comment: For me the imageURL is not displayed beside the link (contentURL)

Comment: Topic starter is talking about the iOS share functionality. Not the one specific to the Facebook SDK

Comment: Sharing only image is not working for me, when Facebook app is not installed on the phone, it doesn't open safari by default. do you know why?